# Configure ASP WebApi external login to use more than one GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

Is it possible to configure Asp.net Mvc 5 project to use more than one GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions and change the active option at runtime ?

I have two apps configured on Google and what I want to achieve is something like:

```
    var config1 = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "ClientID1",
        ClientSecret = "ClientSecret1" 
    };
    var config2 = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "ClientID2",
        ClientSecret = "ClientSecret2" 
    };

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(config1);
```

And change the config1 to config2 somehow at runtime.
My concrete usecase is to change the configuration depending on the mobile app that want use the external login.

Answer (score -1):

You can subscribe multiple google application,
but you have to give to every one an another callback address.

You can see a discussion about that 
at [OWIN AuthenticationOptions updating at runtime in mvc5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613020/owin-authenticationoptions-updating-at-runtime-in-mvc5-application)

and at http://shazwazza.com/post/configuring-aspnet-identity-oauth-login-providers-for-multi-tenancy/